# xts merge odd behaviour

Tags: r, xts

I have 3 xts objects all of whose indicies are 'Date' objects:

```
    > a
                  a
    1995-01-03 1.76
    1995-01-04 1.69
    > b
                  b
    1995-01-03 1.67
    1995-01-04 1.63
    > c
                   c
    1995-01-03 1.795
    1995-01-04 1.690
```

To verify the indices are the same:

```
    > index(a) == index(b)
    [1] TRUE TRUE
    > index(a) == index(c)
    [1] TRUE TRUE
```

Now I'm seeing this odd behaviour:

```
    > merge.xts(a,b)
                  a    b
    1995-01-03   NA 1.67
    1995-01-03 1.76   NA
    1995-01-04   NA 1.63
    1995-01-04 1.69   NA
```

While the following merge works fine:

```
    > merge.xts(a,c)
                  a     c
    1995-01-03 1.76 1.795
    1995-01-04 1.69 1.690
```

I can't figure out what could possibly be going on here. Any idea?

Update:

```
    > dput(a)
    structure(c(1.76, 1.69), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "", .CLASS = "xts", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(789168240, 789254580), tzone = "", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(2L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "a"))

    > dput(b)
    structure(c(1.67, 1.63), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "", .CLASS = "xts", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = c(789109200, 789195600), .Dim = c(2L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
        NULL, "b"))

    > dput(c)
    structure(c(1.795, 1.69), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "", .CLASS = "xts", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = c(789109200, 789195600), .Dim = c(2L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
        NULL, "c"))
```

Indeed, the problem is that the indices are not identical (as verified by `.index(a) == .index(b)` ). Converting to numeric then recreating an xts and recomputing the dates with `asDate` fixed the problem.

This objects were created from the `to.daily` method from xts.

Comment: Please replace the results of printing `a`, `b`, `c` with the results of `dput(a)`, `dput(b)`, `dput(c)`.

Comment: I'll look into to.period.  Thanks for the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `index()` to verify the indices are the same because it converts the index to whatever is specified by `indexClass()`.  Use `.index` to get the raw numeric index, then you will likely find that:

```
all(.index(a) == .index(b))  # is FALSE
```

You should investigate your data source to see what might be causing this.  For a quick fix, do this:

```
index(b) <- as.Date(index(b))
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems convoluted of course, but the reason is that Date is imprecise.  Anything *within* a calendar day is the same "date".

Somewhere, as Josh alluded to, is the fact that your data are created in different ways/sources.  I'll try and think of a better way to manage this variability - since it isn't a purely novel issue.  Until then:

```
index(x) <- index(x)
```

will do the trick. Why?

As Josh notes, `index(x)` [no `<-` ] takes an underlying POSIX `time_t` representation and converts it into a Date (days since the epoch).  Replacing the original index via `index<-` converts the "Date" back into POSIX time (POSIXct in R, `time_t` in C)

```
 t1 <- Sys.time()
 t2 <- Sys.time()

 as.Date(t1) == as.Date(t2)
 #[1] TRUE

 t1 == t2
 #[1] FALSE


 x1 <- xts(1, t1)
 x2 <- xts(2, t2)


 indexClass(x1) <- "Date"
 indexClass(x2) <- "Date"
 cbind(x1,x2)
            ..1 ..2
 2011-10-06   1  NA
 2011-10-06  NA   2

 .index(cbind(x1,x2))
 [1] 1317925443 1317925447
 attr(,"tzone")
 [1] "America/Chicago"
 attr(,"tclass")
 [1] "Date"

 # ugly, ugly solution
 index(x1) <- index(x1)
 index(x2) <- index(x2)
 cbind(x1,x2)
            ..1 ..2
 2011-10-06   1   2
 .index(cbind(x1,x2))
 [1] 1317877200
```